# how to get number of unzipped files while using Unzip class?

Tags: iphone, unzip, php-ziparchive

I have used ZipArchive class to get unzipped files.I want to display number of unzipped files during the operation of unzipping.can anybody guide me or show me some way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to get it "by default", but in `ZipArchive.mm`, you have this code to open a zip archive;

```
-(BOOL) UnzipOpenFile:(NSString*) zipFile
{
    _unzFile = unzOpen( (const char*)[zipFile UTF8String] );
    if( _unzFile )
    {
        unz_global_info  globalInfo = {0};
        if( unzGetGlobalInfo(_unzFile, &globalInfo )==UNZ_OK )
        {
            NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d entries in the zip file",
                 globalInfo.number_entry] );
        }
    }
    return _unzFile!=NULL;
}
```

It logs the number of files in the zip, so an easy way would be to create a property on the ZipArchive class and save the value to that for later reading.

Comment: thanks for this but i have to get how many files are unzipped

Comment: @D.MKunjadiya Then you'll have to add a counter inside the unzip loop in `UnzipFileTo`. As far as I know, it always unzip all files in the archive, but the above won't know about space issues etc. while unzipping.